# Why doesn't this regular expression work in all cases?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file containing entries like this:

```
@markwarner VIRGINIA - Mark Warner 
@senatorleahy VERMONT - Patrick Leahy NO 
@senatorsanders VERMONT - Bernie Sanders 
@orrinhatch UTAH - Orrin Hatch NO 
@jimdemint SOUTH CAROLINA - Jim DeMint NO 
@senmikelee UTAH -- Mike Lee 
@kaybaileyhutch TEXAS - Kay Hutchison 
@johncornyn TEXAS - John Cornyn 
@senalexander TENNESSEE - Lamar Alexander
```

I have written the following to remove the 'NO' and the dashes using regular expressions:

```
import re

politicians = open('testfile.txt')
text = politicians.read()

# Grab the 'no' votes
# Should be 11 entries
regex = re.compile(r'(no\s@[\w+\d+\.]*\s\w+\s?\w+?\s?\W+\s\w+\s?\w+)', re.I)
no = regex.findall(text)

## Make the list a string
newlist = ' '.join(no)

## Replace the dashes in the string with a space
deldash = re.compile('\s-*\s')
a = deldash.sub(' ', newlist)

# Delete 'NO' in the string
delno = re.compile('NO\s')
b = delno.sub('', a)

# make the string into a list
# problem with @jimdemint SOUTH CAROLINA Jim DeMint
regex2 = re.compile(r'(@[\w\d\.]*\s[\w\d\.]*\s?[\w\d\.]\s?[\w\d\.]*?\s+?\w+)', re.I)
lst1 = regex2.findall(b)

for i in lst1:
    print i
```

When I run the code, it captures the twitter handle, state and full names other than the surname of Jim DeMint. I have stated that I want to ignore case for the regex.

Any ideas? Why is the expression not capturing this surname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing it because his state name contains two words: SOUTH CAROLINA

Have your second regex be this, it should help

```
 (@[\w\d\.]*\s[\w\d\.]*\s?[\w\d\.]\s?[\w\d\.]*?\s+?\w+(?:\s\w+)?)
```

I added

```
(?:\s\w+)?
```

Which is a optional, non capturing group matching a space followed by one or more alphanumeric underscore characters

http://regexr.com?31fv5 shows that it properly matches the input with the NOs and dashes stripped

**EDIT:**
If you want one master regex to capture and split everything properly, after you remove the Nos and dashes, use

```
((@[\w]+?\s)((?:(?:[\w]+?)\s){1,2})((?:[\w]+?\s){2}))
```

Which you can play with here: http://regexr.com?31fvk

The full match is available in $1, the Twitter handle in $2, the State in $3 And the name in $4

Each capturing group works as follows:

```
(@[\w]+?\s)
```

This matches an @ sign followed by at least one but as few characters as possible until a space.

```
((?:(?:[\w]+?)\s){1,2})
```

This matches and captures 1 or two words, which should be the state. This only works because of the next piece, which MUST have two words

```
((?:[\w]+?\s){2})
```

Matches and captures exactly two words, which is defined as few characters as possible followed by a space

Comment: This works well but I don't understand why the optional non-capturing group captures the surname. Shouldn't it use the group to grab the text but not print it? Also, would it be a better idea to use the non-capturing group for possible two-part state names?

Comment: Perhaps, but this would require more work. The problem is your original regex captured a twitter handle followed by two or three words. This one captures a twitter handle followed by two, three or four words.

Answer (score 2):

```
text=re.sub(' (NO|-+)(?= |$)','',text)
```

And to capture everything:

```
re.findall('(@\w+) ([A-Z ]+[A-Z]) (.+?(?= @|$))',text)
```

Or all at once:

```
re.findall('(@\w+) ([A-Z ]+[A-Z])(?: NO| -+)? (.+?(?= @|$))',text)
```

Comment: These are where I'm heading. New to regex, so this is helpful. The middle one seems to only return the last three groups in the string when I iterate and print the list.